# Display country by typing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I would like to display the country name by start typing (without scrolling).

This is what I have tried out: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-poq5gz)

All the countries will get listed but if I type something, nothing happens.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to create is pipe filter:

**[Online Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-poq5gz-gbffag)**

like

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

export interface Country{
  name: String,
  code: String
}

@Pipe({ name: 'myCountry' })
export class CountryPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(allCountries: Country[], search: string) {
    if (search){
      return allCountries.filter((country:Country) => country.name.includes(search));
    }
    return allCountries;
  }
}
```

Add it to your declarations in your app module like:

```
declarations: [AutocompleteFilterExample, CountryPipe],
```

This would allow you to filter while you type when added to your **ngFor** like:

```
   <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option 
       *ngFor="let country of (countries | myCountry:myControl.value )" 
        [value]="country.name">
        {{country.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're very close, but since your list of countries has both 'name' and 'code' you must edit your _filter function to filter on desired value 'name'

Check out this Angular Material [example](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values) and accompanying [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/enrjnbxvxqk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts)

Answer (score 1):

To give a simple answer, your problem is just with this line per Rydyell.

`return this.countries.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));`

TypeScript would really help with this by the way if you define an interface for countries it will show you the problem here.

`option` here is an object (`{"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}`) and you need to filter on a property, not the whole thing - so like this:

`return this.countries.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));`